# Where is my JVM memory leak? Garbage collector is working properly?

Tags: java, scala, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a Scala daemon application, that runs in a server in Rackspace with a limit of 2GB. Because of an unknown reason, the server get stuck after some time the application is running. I am suspecting there is a memory leak, because the server memory gets full after some time.

I tried to run jvisualvm, making snapshots of memory in two different moments and compare them to see if there were objects that remained allocated, but I could not find anything.

The heap allocation is just around 400MB. Here is a snapshot of the JVM memory in New Relic:

[image]

Notice that PS Eden Space heap is what keeps increasing. I did a work around that kills the application every 3 hours and starts it back again (this is why the graph suddenly goes back down).

Any idea of why this PS Eden is increasing? How to fix it?

**Edit 1:**
Screenshot of the machine that halted minutes before 13:00
[image]

**Edit 2:**
On a new round, a left the server hang itself, and used G1GC. Here is the new relic graph for this run:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's heap allocations causing the problem? It looks like your PermGen is pegged to its max the entire time (assuming you haven't increased it from the default setting). Scala loads a lot of classes.

Comment: Perm size is configured with -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m

Comment: What are your other jvm options (if any)?

Comment: -javaagent:/home/ubuntu/bigear/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m

Comment: I don't think you should be allotting all of the physical memory to the JVM like that. It's probably paging to a file and grinding to a halt.

Comment: Have you tried using a different garbage collector, such as G1GC, to see if that sheds any more light on the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's normal that the Eden grows constantly, that is where new objects are allocated. Eden will keep growing until it get's full or until a partial collection runs that collects unused objects, and shifts objects being used to the survivor region S0.

This is as per the way this type of garbage collection was designed. The idea is that it's OK that Eden is full, we let it grow and garbage collect it only when it's most convenient, minimizing the impact for application code.

Try to remove the workaround, let the server freeze and see if there are any out of memory errors in the logs. Too many classes would have cause such errors.

Try to see if the OldGen is full. Then using visualvm, force a garbage collection, and see if it goes down. If it doesn't, there is the problem.

Then take a heap dump and a thread dump and analyse the heap dump in [MAT - Eclipse Memory Analyser tool](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/), see this [tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/) as well. it could be that the server just needs more memory.

One important notion, in Java there is really no notion of a memory leak, the garbage collector works mostly flawlessly to collect unused objects.

Usually the problem comes from objects that are created but are for example kept around in static collections or thread local variables accidentally, and because they are referenced get never collected.

A tool that has a free trial and allows to generate a report that pinpoints a lot of these common causes is [Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu/). That is probably the best chance at a quick solution, try to run plumbr to see if it finds something, if not then MAT analisys of the heap dump.

Comment: I tried Plumbr, no Leak found with this tool. 
I think the hang occurs because I use swap memory and the Rackspace server does not do good with swap (high IO kills the servers)